# A sloppy calculation

Tags: mathematics, calculation-puzzle, no-computers

Little Johnny Red forgot to write the multiplication sign between two 3-digit numbers $x$ and $y$ and simply wrote them as one number. When Johnny's teacher graded the homework, it turned out that the 6-digit number written by Johnny was three times the correct product $xy$.

Find the positive integers $x$ and $y$!

Comment: The phrase "three times greater than" is problematic. I generally take its intent to be "three times as much as", but the literal meaning should be "four times as much as", because 3x + x =4x.  Please clarify the meaning.

Comment: @Gamow *x is three times* **x = 3y** *greater than y* **y +** *x is three times greater than y* **x = y + 3x** if you can read that.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The only answer is

> $167$ and $334$.

I formulated the question as follows:

> If the numbers are $x$ and $y$, then $1000x + y = 3xy$.

This can be rewritten as

> $y=\frac{1000x}{3x-1}$

If

> If $3x-1$ is to completely divide $1000$, and $x$ is a three-digit number, then $3x-1$ can be only equal to $500$. Then $x$ solves to $167$ and $y$ is $334$.

Comment: Note that $(3x-1)$ and $x$ won't share any prime factors in common. Therefore if $(3x-1)$ divides evenly into $1000x$, then $(3x-1)$ must divide $1000$.

Comment: Once you get here $y=\frac{1000x}{3x-1}$, given that $100 \le x \le 999$, $y = 334$.

Answer (score 13):

Let's say that $x$ and $y$ are the 3 digit numbers, then

> $3*x*y = 1000x + y$
>  $3y = 1000 + y/x$
>
>  That number $y/x$ is positive and less than 10, because $y<=999$ and $x>=100$, so we can rewrite this equation as:
>
>  $1000 < 3y < 1010$
>  $333.3 < y < 336.7$
>
>  So $y$ can be 334, 335 or 336
>
>  Substitute these values to our equation and we get the following:
>
>  $3x*334 = 1000x + 334$
>  $1002x-1000x = 334$
>  $x = 167$
>
>  So 334 and 167 is a match
>
>  $3x*335 = 1000x + 335$
>  $5x = 335$
>  $x = 67$
>
>  67 is a 2 digit number, so y can't be 335
>
>  $3x*336 = 1000x + 336$
>  $8x = 336$
>  $x = 42$
>
>  42 is also not a 3 digit number, so y can't be 336

Therefore the only answer is:

> 334 and 167

Check that this answer is valid:

> $334*167 = 55778$
>  $55778 * 3 = 167334$

Answer (score 10):

One answer would be

> $167\times334\ (\times3 = 167334)$

How I found it:

> The easiest way to have at least one of the numbers $x$ in the product with $3$ is if the other number $y$ multiplied with $3$ is a bit over $1000$. The smallest such $y$ is $334$ which gives, multiplied with $3$, the product $1002$. Afterwards we only need an $x$ that multiplied with $2$ gives us $334$; therefore $x = 167$.

Answer (score 3):

Because who doesn't like brute force? (And because the answer is already here)

python2:

```
>>> for i in range(100,1000):
...     for j in range(100, 1000):
...             if 1000*i + j == 3*i*j:
...                     print i, j
...
```

> 167 334

For numbers this size it's quicker than working it out 'properly'

Comment: I think the intent was to do it without a program, given the "no-computers" tag.

Comment: @dpwilson, that'll teach me to not read tags